# Control white space of section locally on latex

Tags: latex, text-styling

is there a way to control the white space above just one specific section in latex? Most solutions I've found rely on the titlesec package, but as far as I know that would change every section.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `\vspace*{length}` command, just before your section begins. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
  \lipsum

  \section{Section 1}
  \lipsum

  \vspace*{1cm}
  \section{Section moved down}
  \lipsum
\end{document}
```

moves the second section 1cm down.